# Check if a polygon is a multipolygon in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

How can I check if a polygon entity is actually a multipolygon?
I've tried:

```
if len(polygon) > 1:
```

but then get the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Polygon' has no len()
```

I've tried `Nill`, `None` and others, nothing worked.

Comment: You should check the manual. You can read about `class MultiPolygon` here: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#collections-of-polygons

Comment: This works only if your variable is a multipolygon. If it is not - you`ll get that error. This is why I want to check whether my variable is a polygon or a multipolygon.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the `object.geom_type` string (see [general attributes and methods](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#general-attributes-and-methods)).

For example:

```
if poly.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
    # do multipolygon things.
elif poly.geom_type == 'Polygon':
    # do polygon things.
else:
    # raise IOError('Shape is not a polygon.')
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this worked for me:

```
print ('type = ', type(poly))
```

outputs with:

```
type =  <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

in case of a polygon, and:

```
type =  <class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>
```

in case of a multipolygon.

To check if a variable is a polygon or a multypolygon I did this:

```
if (isinstance(poly, shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon)):
    code...
```

Comment: Worth noting that this will not tell you how many rings the multipolygon has. A multipolygon may have only one exterior ring. That may not matter for your use case.

Comment: Using your `isinstance()` code, I get: `NameError: name 'shapely' is not defined`

Comment: @jane that means you have not imported shapely (or not as shapely). Add `import shapely` to the top of your code

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply.

```py
import shapely.geometry.multipolygon as sh

if isinstance(polygon, sh.MultiPolygon):
    print('yes I am')
```